# Add LINK to a Chainlink Keeper Upkeep

Tags: solidity, chainlink, chainlink-keepers

I have a job on the [Chainlink Keeper](https://keepers.chain.link/mainnet) network, and I have a system to collect `LINK` token.

Is it possible to fund my keeper job without having to go through the UI in solidity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, anyone can call the `addFunds` function on the [keeper registry contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7b3EC232b08BD7b4b3305BE0C044D907B2DF960B#code).

```
  function addFunds(
    uint256 id,
    uint96 amount
  )
```

You'd just need to pass in the keeper jobId and the amount you want to fund it with.